# Cell number from formula

Tags: excel

To start off im not very experienced with excel, and also on google i could not find any info relating this question. Hopefully anyone here will know a smart way for this:

In excel when you want the content from a cell into another cell you can just do (for example in A1) =C1

But in my case i need the following:
(line 1) In cell A1 i need the value from C12
(line 2) in cell A2 i need the value from C24
(line 3) in cell A3 i need the value from C36
..
and so on.

So for Each Ax the cell i need is C(x*12)

it looks like doing something like =C(10+2) is not possible in Excel.
So i wonder, is there a smart way of doing this? i cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options (starting in A1):

`=INDIRECT("C"&ROW()*12)`

or

`=INDEX($C:$C,ROW()*12)`

The latter is faster (as non-volatile) in large datasets, the former is more flexible...

Comment: @Sam: I always prefer `INDEX`, the non-volatility can make quite a difference in large workbooks

Comment: Thanx this helped me a lot. Horrable Office though translates "ROW" into my default language... so it wont understand when i use the english word

Comment: that's usually annoying that Excel's local versions use local formula names. But then I guess many Excel users prefer it that way... :-( If you only know the english formula (E.g. from SO), then goto the VB Editor's Immediate window (Alt-F11, Ctrl-G) and simply enter `Selection.Formula="=INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()*12)` - and you'll see the local formula. (Note the double `"`!)